# What does solid matrix mean?

Tags: food-chemistry, reference-request

I am reading "Effect of Freeze-Drying on Quality and Grinding
Process of Food Produce": [A Review by Timilehin Martins Oyinloye and Won Byong Yoon](https://doi.org/10.3390/pr8030354).

The problem is they are referring to the words "sold matrix" several times. I searched the internet but could not understand what does that mean. Any comments please? Is this term used in some other area not in Chemistry?

[Full Text](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-9717/8/3/354/htm)

Comment: A glass of orange juice is a liquid matrix. Freeze it solid, and it is a solid matrix. Rocks, like the ones the Perseverance rover will soon be zapping on Mars, are solid matrices. Techniques like LIBS (laser induced breakdown spectroscopy) typically are used with solid matrix samples, e.g., rocks, alloys, etc.

Comment: Well, "sold matrix" can be both solid matrix or liquid matrix. Quoted typos have tendency to be perceived as intention, but in food industry context, sold matrix makes sense as well. I suggest reading [Wikipedia : Matrix_(chemical_analysis)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(chemical_analysis))